# Install IJulia on Julia 1.0.0

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

I just installed Julia and would now like to install the IJulia notebook. However, compilation fails:

```
julia> Pkg.build("IJulia")
  Building Conda ──→ `~/.julia/packages/Conda/m7vem/deps/build.log`
  Building ZMQ ────→ `~/.julia/packages/ZMQ/yClfT/deps/build.log`
  Building MbedTLS → `~/.julia/packages/MbedTLS/Qo8TN/deps/build.log`
  Building IJulia ─→ `~/.julia/packages/IJulia/iMVN2/deps/build.log`
┌ Error: Error building `IJulia`: 
│ ┌ Warning: Could not execute `jupyter --version`.
│ └ @ Main ~/.julia/packages/IJulia/iMVN2/deps/build.jl:38
│ [ Info: Installing Jupyter via the Conda package.
│ [ Info: Downloading miniconda installer ...
│ ERROR: LoadError: IOError: could not spawn `curl -g -L -f -o /home/user001/.julia/packages/Conda/m7vem/deps/usr/installer.sh https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh`: no such file or directory (ENOENT)
│ Stacktrace:
│  [1] _jl_spawn(::String, ::Array{String,1}, ::Cmd, ::Tuple{RawFD,RawFD,RawFD}) at ./process.jl:367
│  [2] (::getfield(Base, Symbol("##495#496")){Cmd})(::Tuple{RawFD,RawFD,RawFD}) at ./process.jl:509
│  [3] setup_stdio(::getfield(Base, Symbol("##495#496")){Cmd}, ::Tuple{RawFD,RawFD,RawFD}) at ./process.jl:490
│  [4] #_spawn#494(::Nothing, ::Function, ::Cmd, ::Tuple{RawFD,RawFD,RawFD}) at ./process.jl:508
│  [5] _spawn at ./process.jl:504 [inlined]
│  [6] #run#505(::Bool, ::Function, ::Cmd) at ./process.jl:652
│  [7] run at ./process.jl:651 [inlined]
│  [8] download(::String, ::String) at ./download.jl:48
│  [9] macro expansion at ./logging.jl:311 [inlined]
│  [10] _install_conda(::String, ::Bool) at /home/user001/.julia/packages/Conda/m7vem/src/Conda.jl:146
│  [11] _install_conda(::String) at /home/user001/.julia/packages/Conda/m7vem/src/Conda.jl:145
│  [12] runconda(::Cmd, ::String) at /home/user001/.julia/packages/Conda/m7vem/src/Conda.jl:111
│  [13] add at /home/user001/.julia/packages/Conda/m7vem/src/Conda.jl:174 [inlined] (repeats 2 times)
│  [14] top-level scope at logging.jl:311
│  [15] top-level scope at /home/user001/.julia/packages/IJulia/iMVN2/deps/build.jl:38
│  [16] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
│  [17] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1038
│  [18] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
│  [19] include(::String) at ./client.jl:388
│  [20] top-level scope at none:0
│ in expression starting at /home/user001/.julia/packages/IJulia/iMVN2/deps/build.jl:9
└ @ Pkg.Operations /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:1068
```

The file pointed out actually exists and I am able to fetch it:

```
$ wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
--2018-08-27 16:29:15--  https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
Resolving repo.continuum.io (repo.continuum.io)... 104.16.18.10, 104.16.19.10, 2400:cb00:2048:1::6810:130a, ...
Connecting to repo.continuum.io (repo.continuum.io)|104.16.18.10|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 58468498 (56M) [application/x-sh]
Saving to: ‘Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh’

Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh               100%[======================================================================================================>]  55,76M   102MB/s    in 0,5s    

2018-08-27 16:29:16 (102 MB/s) - ‘Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh’ saved [58468498/58468498]
```

What's wrong?

**Update**: regarding the concernes with the `.julia/packages/Conda/m7vem/deps/usr/` folder, all appears correct:

```
$ ll /home/user001/.julia/packages/Conda/m7vem/deps/usr/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 user001 user001 4096 aug 27 15:56 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 user001 user001 4096 aug 27 15:56 ../
```

Comment: Maybe check your curl version. This was an issue for me at some point. It should be >7.5. UPDATE: sorry, I guess you have a different issue here.

Comment: I have `curl` 7.58.

Comment: The error is probably not about fetching it's about that the directory `/home/user001/.julia/packages/Conda/m7vem/deps/usr/` does not exist or is not writeable. Check the permissions or try to create a file in this directory within your julia instance. Do you get an error?

Comment: Note that "as a workaround", you may also try installing Jupyter outside Julia and let IJulia find your Jupyter installation.